# SSRS subscription stuck in running state

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms, ssrs-2012, windows-server-2008

I have a subscription in SSRS that saves the report to windows file share.

[image: Stuck in Run state]

When I manually ran this subscription, it's result is stuck in running state. Although, when trying to create a report without subscription it successfully did that in the windows file share directory.

I tried looking into the folder permissions, but that's not the issue.

**Background**

The SSRS is a separate standalone server interacting with another SQL Server. Both SQL and SSRS are on separate remote servers.

Connectivity can't be an issue as reports are being generated without subscriptions (this also rules out any issue with permissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay, so this was some error from the SQL Server end, and running the following queries worked wonders.

**PS:** Anyone who can explain why these worked is most welcome

Begin by running the following query in SSMS (Press Ctrl + N in SSMS to run a new query)

```
USE master
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_notify TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_is_starting TO RSExecRole
GO
```

Then, run the following query

```
USE msdb
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_help_category TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_add_category TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_add_job TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_help_job TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobschedule TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.sp_verify_job_identifiers TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT SELECT ON msdb.dbo.sysjobs TO RSExecRole
GO
GRANT SELECT ON msdb.dbo.syscategories TO RSExecRole
GO
```

Then disable and enable the subscription or create a new subscription and run it. This should work!